# Google Tag Manager on iOS and BomStream

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

After installing Google Tag Manager on a iOS app and run it, Log window shows those messages:

```
GoogleTagManager verbose: Setting refresh time to saved time: 1473923915880
GoogleTagManager verbose: scheduleTask: containerId=GTM-XX4TR delay=38581836.764893
BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory
GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 +[GAITrackerModel initialize] (GAITrackerModel.m:88): idfa class missing, won't collect idfa
GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:518): Saved hit:
```

What does it mean this BOMStream output? It seems not to affect the overall functioning of the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BOMStream isn't a public or internal class in Google Tag Manager. Is it possible that this event is occurring on another thread during startup? A quick search of StackOverflow indicates that this might be related to Titanium/Appcelerator.